# jQuery Validation form is not Validating and submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, form-submit

I've set all rules correctly, yet they seem to be ignored completely when I submit the Form.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#formValidation').validate({
    rules: {
      name: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2,
        lettersonly: true,
      },
      email: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 5,
        email: true,
      },
      feedback: {
        required: true,
        minWords: 5,
      },
    }
    messages: {
      name: {
        required: "Please enter your name",
      },
    },
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<form id="formValidation" onload="validate()">
  <p>Name: <br/><input type="text" name="name" /> </p>
  <p>Email:<br/><input type="email" name="email" /></p>
  <p>Feedback:<br/><input type="text" name="feedback" id="textfield" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" onsubmit="return formValidation()" /> </p>
</form>
```

Comment: There is no need for `onsubmit` event in the submit input element and for `onload` in the form element.

Comment: Also, might sound strange, but are you loading the jquery validate plugin?

Comment: I am loading the plugin. I followed LShetty's advice and got the same result. It seems to ignore everything and submit the form regardless

Answer (score 1):

So, all you need is the following.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#formValidation').validate({ 
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2,
                lettersonly:true,
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
                email:true,
            },
            feedback: {
                required: true,
                minWords: 5,
            }
        },
        messages: {
            name:{
                required:"Please enter your name",
            }
        }
    });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<form id="formValidation" method="post">
    <p>Name: <br/><input type="text" name="name" /> </p>
    <p>Email:<br/><input type="email" name="email" /></p>
    <p>Feedback:<br/><input type="text" name="feedback" id="textfield"/>
    <input type="submit" id="submit"/> </p>
</form>
```

- Removed unnecessary/extra `,`s from your script.
- Remove inline event handlers

Comment: Hey LShetty, thanks for replying, I followed your feedback accordingly and the result is the same when I run it . However it works when I run the code snippet on Stackoverflow

Comment: I would guess that either your links to the validate script are not working, or you've attached something else to the submit event of the form that is intercepting those events.